# How do i have a jar communicate with another jar

Tags: java, io, ipc, executable-jar

Ok so i have 2 jars (Console, Core)

1st-Console) receives user input

2nd-Core) processes the input and gives an output

i'm trying to have the two "Communicate" with each other by exchanging input and output

now i have tried writing to a file to communicate when i ran into the problem of "Notifying" the other that there is input to receive and output to give

i'm a bit new to this ideal so if its an easy function, please don't criticize.

Comment: The world of Java, in which Jars talking to each other is commonplace ;)

Comment: Assuming these two are separate processes You can use [Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html), [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) etc

Comment: So, is this about interprocess communication or a class path issue?

Comment: http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html   , make console.jar as a client and Core.jar as a server.

Comment: Make them see each other with classpath. Then you can instantiate a jar's classes from the other.

Comment: @Edwin Yes this is interprocess communications

Comment: Look at the [Observer-Observable pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one process (which has nothing to do with having more than one Jar file), then you can simply use one Jar file in another.

But, if you are running your Jar files separately, then you have two different processes and what you need is Inter Process Communication which can be done in various ways:

- **[Remote Method Invocation(RMI):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Remote_Method_Invocation)** which allows a process to execute a function in another process in another address space
- **[Network Sockets:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)** That allows you to send serialized data between various processes.

Comment: There are [a few other ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), of course, like sharing the data in a common place (i.e. file or a database), passing messages (i.e. message queues), in linux or any other POSIX OS you could use pipes, etc. etc., etc. Other forms of remote method invocation like XML-RPC or JSON-RPC, web services in general. Anyways, the book is full of tested tricks.

Comment: Absolutely, I just sampled two. Thanks for your comment :)